# What would you call a non-persistent data structure that allows persistent operations?

Tags: python, data-structures, functional-programming, persistence, naming

I've got a class that is essentially mutable, but allows for some "persistent-like" operations.  For example, I can mutate the object like this (in Python):

```
# create an object with y equal to 3 and z equal to "foobar"
x = MyDataStructure(y = 3, z = "foobar") 
x.y = 4
```

However, in lieu of doing things this way, there are a couple of methods that instead make a copy and then mutate it:

```
x = MyDataStructure(y=3, z="foobar")
# a is just like x, but with y equal to 4.
a = x.using(y = 4)
```

This is making a duplicate of x with different values.  Apparently, this doesn't meet the definition of partially persistent given by [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure).

So what would you call a class like this? QuasiPersistentObject?  PersistableObject?  SortOfPersistentObject? Better yet, are there any technical names for this?

Comment: Are you mixing the terms persistent (survives a restart) and muteable (is allowed to have values modified)? These are very different and appear to be used interchangeably in the question.

Comment: Yes, it seems what you call persistent is actually meant to be immutable. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object

Comment: @haffax:  Persistent data structures are by nature immutable, but immutable data structures and persistent datastructures aren't quite the same thing.  See the wikipedia link in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I call this kind of data **Persistable** but not sure if it's a word
.

Comment: That's the first word that came to my mind too, but it seemed a little bit made up to me as well.  :-)

Comment: Persistable is a totally cromulent word, no matter what my browser's dictionary tells me. Not only is it cromulent, but also quite performant. My dictionary just needs to be embiggened...

Answer (score 2):

It's just a optimized copy, I'd rather rename the operation to reflect that.

```
a = x.copy_with(y=4)
```

Comment: I like the way in which types in the datetime standard library module express this concept -- they name the method `replace` (of course, they ARE immutable types, so it should be clear they return a tweaked copy rather than mutate the original;-).

Comment: That's another way to do it.  I had kind of intended for this to have a fluent interface.  It reads like english:  "x using y equal to 4".